# CodeIgniter: Query with WHERE returns an error :: $query = $this->db->query()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I need to get `guest_id` from `new_guest` table where column `guest_nic_pp_dl` is equal to the variable `guest_nic_pp_dl` and `LIMIT` to 1 result. However the code I wrote ends in a silly syntax error. How can I define WHERE with a variable value to match rows?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$guest_nic_pp_dl' (T_VARIABLE) in    C:\xampp\htdocs\bit\application\models\reservations_model.php on line 20

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT guest_id FROM new_guest WHERE guest_nic_pp_dl, '$guest_nic_pp_dl' LIMIT 1'); // Line 20
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    return $row->guest_id;
```

Comment: WHERE guest_nic_pp_dl = '$guest_nic_pp_dl'

Comment: Still the same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it like that

```
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT guest_id FROM new_guest WHERE guest_nic_pp_dl, '$guest_nic_pp_dl' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 2):

`$this->db->select('guest_id');`

`$this->db->where('guest_nic_pp_dl', $guest_nic_pp_dl);`

`$this->db->limit(1);`

`$query = $this->db->get('new_guest');`

Comment: Personally, I don't like this way but I'll keep this in mind in case if necessary. Thanks! :)

Comment: I'd advice to dig into CI active record as much as possible.. may seem obvious for simple queries, but makes life much easier and DB independant.. besides it auto escapes your variables...

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT guest_id FROM new_guest WHERE guest_nic_pp_dl='.$guest_nic_pp_dl.' LIMIT 1');
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
return $row->guest_id;
}
```